# Mapping key in the tmux command prompt

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, keymap

I would like to map `<C-p>` to `<Up>` in the context of the tmux command prompt (the one that is opened by pressing `<prefix>:`) so that when pressing it, previous executed commands are displayed in order.

The reason why I want to do this is because I tend to execute `tmux` commands in the command prompt. One scenario is when moving multiple panes from the current opened session to another session. What I would do is to toggle the command prompt and execute `:join-pane -t <session-name>`, then I would move to the other pane I want to move from the current session, toggle the comand prompt again and press the `<Up>` key in order not to type the whole command again. However, this method involves moving my right hand from the home row. Mapping `<C-p>` to `<Up>` avoids that.

The only potential feature I found helpful for accomplishing this was the `bind-key` command. However, mapping keys for the command prompt is not mentioned in the documentation of that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to configure the keys at the command prompt.

However, tmux has supported `C-p` and `C-n` in the command prompt with emacs keys for a long time: `set -g status-keys emacs`.